# Android ошибка при добавлении в ListView

Tags: android

Приложение падает с ошибкой при загрузке данных в ListView

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.example.danilshik.myapplication.SelectCityActivity$SelectCity.onPostExecute(SelectCityActivity.java:155)
                      at com.example.danilshik.myapplication.SelectCityActivity$SelectCity.onPostExecute(SelectCityActivity.java:76)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2139 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Имеется код

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ArrayList<String> cityArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray cities = null;
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            Log.e("sdfsdfsdf",result);
            try {

                jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                int success = jsonObject.getInt("success");

                if(success==1){
                    cities = jsonObject.getJSONArray("cities");

                    for (int i = 0; i<cities.length();i++){
                        JSONObject paramCities = cities.getJSONObject(i);
                        int id = paramCities.getInt("id");

                        String region = paramCities.getString("region");
                        String autonom = paramCities.getString("autonom");
                        String area = paramCities.getString("area");
                        String city = paramCities.getString("city");
                        String city_2 = paramCities.getString("city_2");
                        City city1 = new City(id, region, autonom, area, city, city_2);
                        cityArrayList.add(city1.getTitle());
                        Log.e("Opa",city1.getTitle());
                    }

                }
                else{
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SelectCityActivity.this, "Такого населенного пункта в базе нет", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            pDialog.cancel();
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(SelectCityActivity.this, 
            R.layout.activity_select_city,cityArrayList);
            citiesList.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
```

Судя по ошибки, проблема в строчке установки adapter

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(SelectCityActivity.this, 
                R.layout.activity_select_city,cityArrayList);
citiesList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

В чем ошибка?

**Update:** Как можно добавить для ListView обработчик:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        citiesListView.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                City city = cityObjectArrayList.get(position);
                String text = String.valueOf(city.getId());
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(SelectCityActivity.this, text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        })
```

Выдает ошибку

```
setOnClickListener
(android.view.View.OnClickListener)
in AdapterView cannot be applied
to
(anonymous android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)
```

Comment: Какая-то переменная null. Наверное `cityArrayList`. Проверьте, что она инициализирована

Comment: Посмотрите инициализирована ли citiesList?

Comment: @РасулA-ев это элемент ListView, сейчас переименовал citiesList в citiesListView, чтобы было понято. Инициализация citiesListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.citiesList);

Comment: @ЮрийСПб первой строчкой после начала метода она инициализирована, не?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб перед установкой адаптера ее длина составляет 357

Comment: А, тогда, наверное, у вас разметка не та. Попробуйте вот эту: `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`. Замените ею `R.layout.activity_select_city`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб такой разметки нет. Что оно представляет собой? Layout активити, на которой расположен ListView, или что-то другое? Если что-то другое, то как добавить, по умолчанию у меня не создался он

Comment: @danilshik, это системная разметка. В адаптер надо передать разметку со строго определёнными ID и наличием `TextView` - именно в ней будет отображна инфа из списка переданных данных. Точнее - результат вызова `toString()`. Да, можно свою разметку подставить, но она должна быть составлена по жёстким правилам. Разметка активити тут совсем не подходит

Comment: @ЮрийСПб можете тогда скинуть код системной разметки. Я создам layout и вставлю туда ее

Comment: Просто используйте ту что я написал. Можете ее сразу и посмотреть.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ее не видит android studio, поэтому я и спрашиваю

Comment: а извините, я не увидел android перед R.layout

Comment: К сожалению ошибка осталась. На данный момент код выглядит так:ListView citiesListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.citiesList); ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SelectCityActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cityArrayList);
                    citiesListView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Есть еще варианты, из-за чего может быть ошибка?

Comment: Больше ничего не придумать. Запускайте дебаггер и ищите где null

Comment: @ЮрийСПб проблема оказалась в ListView. Я перенес строчку в onPostExecute citiesListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.citiesList) из onCreate и все заработало. Только не понятно почему он не видит элемент, ведь все элементы должны в onCreate прописывать

Comment: Может оно у вас было до `setContentView` прописано? Не видя всего кода ничего конкретного сказать нельзя

Comment: @ЮрийСПб как можно добавить обработчик для ListView? Посмотрите конец вопроса, там представлен код и ошибка

Comment: @danilshik, в одном вопросе должен быть один вопрос) Задайте отдельный вопрос. А так - надо использовать другой интерфейс. Точнее другой метод для назначения этого интерфейса, не `setOnClickListener` а что-то типа `setOnItemClickListener`. Ну и у вас явно нет `setContentView` и вы опять в то же самое NPE уткнётесь